# Vuex state property name - convention or requirement?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

From all tutorials on Vuex that I've read, the state is always maintained in a property named `state` in the `Vuex.Store` object.

My question is whether this property has to be named `state` or can it be named something else? From my experiments, it seems that it has to be called `state`, but I would like to have confirmation from people who are more experienced in Vue.

Related, does the Vuex store have to be named as `store` in Vue as a requirement or convention?

`new Vue({
  ...
  store,
  ...
});`

My hunch is that `store` is a strong convention - breaking it would break interoperability with plugins, and that `state` seems to be a requirement in `Vuex.Store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be called state.

If you named it something else, how should Vuex know that you intend for that other property to represent the state?

However the store instance can be named anything you want - but the property hat you add to the `new Vue` has to be called `store`:

```
const myStore = new Vuex.Store(...) // name this variable as you want

new Vue({
  ...
  store: myStore, // but the property has to be called `store`
  ...
});
```